# forEach() running through divs in JS gives error

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a few divs in an array that I want to change the height on, and even though when I log the names of the divs and it gives me the right object names, I still get a "this is undefined" error message in the console.

Like I said, when I log out all the names of the divs they are correctly given through, but on the line where I want to set their height, I guess that there is a problem with "this" somewhere.

```
this.divs.forEach(names);
    function names(div) {
    console.log(div);  //goes thought all the divs correctly
    this._renderer.setElementStyle(div.nativeElement, 'height', largestHeight + 'px');
    }
```

I am doing it in angular2 in case someone was wondering. 
Regards for any help.

Comment: Maybe try `forEach(names.bind(this))`, looks like a scoping issue.

Comment: Thanks, answer correct like the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `this` in your function context, try to use arrow function:

```
this.divs.forEach((names) => {
   ...
});
```

You can also bind `this` to your function.

```
this.divs.forEach(names.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks allot, marked correct for it was first in the line.  :)

Comment: @Alfa 'a lot'; 'allot' means 'allocate'.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here

```
function names(div) {
```

In JavaScript this is belonging to the current function unless you pass another `this`:

```
this.divs.forEach(names.bind(this));
```

or in ES6

```
let names = (div) => {
  console.log(div);  //goes thought all the divs correctly
  this._renderer.setElementStyle(div.nativeElement, 'height', largestHeight + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helped allot and I will read up on this more.